# The brightness gets reset after unlocking

Tags: unity, laptop, brightness, asus

I'm getting this annoying behaviour (didn't occur on any of the previous releases), every time the display gets lock after typing the password the brightness is **reset to 100%**. But when I open the "**Brightness & Lock**" the brightness level is restored... Does anyone have a similar behaviour ?

Using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity (i915) on a Asus N55SF.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Problem solved by adding `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` to the line that begins with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=** inside */etc/default/grub*

Dont forget to call **update-grub** after

Thanks,
Leandro

Comment: Hi. Request you to post a sample of the grub file, and highlight the changes you've done...

Answer (score 0):

The OP post this answer as a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138386/the-brightness-gets-reset-after-unlocking#comment165078_138386):

> Problem solved by adding `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` to the
>   line that begins with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` inside
>   */etc/default/grub*. Dont forget to call `update-grub` after.